# Cannot install application in Android Tablet

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio to develop an app which used Camera2 API. I can run the app in Google Nexus 9, however the app is not installed in the device and I cannot access it once I close the app. What am I doing wrong ?

Here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.map" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="test.camera.main" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="key"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


</application>
```

Comment: Well, if you run the app, then it *is* installed. And by default it is not uninstalled from a device afterwards.

Comment: Yes the application runs, but is not installed, that is the problem here. What should I look into?

Comment: why you're registering MainActivity twice ? Also pass correct action to it.

Comment: try to change the second activity name like(MainActivity to SecondActivity), otherwise some conflicts may occur

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your < activity > in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
```

EDIT: added sample

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.mycompany.android.myapp"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >
   <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="9"
      android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <application
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
      <activity
         android:name=".ActFirst"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity
         android:name=".ActSecond" >
      </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I have that in manifest, I realized that the application is listed in the list of applications when I got to Settings>Apps. But I cannot run it from anywhere, as I cannot see any icon related to the app in the device.

Comment: you don't have what I said in there. you have android.intent.action.map instead of android.intent.action.MAIN.

Comment: also missing package and android:versionCode+android:versionName and <uses-sdk>

Comment: @steelbytes versionCode, versionName and <uses-sdk> can be defined in build.gradle file, no need to define it in manifest as he is using Android Studio. Also you can write package name in your module's build.gradle file which is as known as applicationId instead of package name in gradle script.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, thanks.  didn't know that.  haven't made the jump to AS yet :-)

Comment: @steelbytes No Problem :-) I would say start using Android Studio and stop using Eclipse Crap. Studio is way better than Eclipse.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, tried it and swore a lot :-(   plus looks horrible on my 4K monitor on windows - google has said they wont fix this until 1.2 :-(

Comment: @moleculeone, to appear in the launcher, you must have what I originally said in one of your activities.

Comment: @moleculeone That's okay if it is map activity. You don't need to define it is in action. Also, for an application to run, it must contain one MAIN activity which can be launched for the first time. So pass correct action to it as steelbytes suggested you, Good Luck ;-)

Comment: @steelbytes I would love to help with Android Studio, if you need me, you may find me in [java and android era](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era) room in IST.

Answer (score 0):

While running my app, I thought I had the same problem.

The problem in my app was the **app_name** in the strings file was different that what I thought it is. So Basically I was looking for app **"X"** while the name i gave is **"Y"**.

Maybe you have the same problem.